# crontab for scheduling a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, teradata

I am trying to schedule a shell script (batch1.sh) contatining the following command using crontab:

```
/opt/teradata/client/14.10/datamover/commandline/datamove start -job_name DM_JOB_PROPOSAL_CREDIT_LIMIT -sync > /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.out 2>&1
```

the command datamove is a Teradata datamover command.

Following is the crontab entry to schedule the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
57 15 * * * /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh
```

I am getting "unable to access DmCommandline.jar" error.

output of crontab -l:

```
#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
#(/tmp/crontab.XXXX4NWuZV installed on Thu Apr  3 15:55:46 2014)
#(Cron version V5.0 -- $Id: crontab.c,v 1.12 2004/01/23 18:56:42 vixie Exp $)
#50 18 * * * CMD datamove start -job_name DM_JOB_LIMIT_DETAILS -sync >> /home/out.out
#18 19 * * * sh /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/01042014_ZA/batch1.sh

#!/bin/bash
57 15 * * * /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh
```

Comment: So what do you have if you do `crontab -l`? Also, note that you might need to add `/bin/bash` (or whatever coming from `bin bash`) in front of `/home/dmuser/...` in the `57 15 * * *` line.

Comment: output of crontab -l: # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.XXXX4NWuZV installed on Thu Apr  3 15:55:46 2014)
# (Cron version V5.0 -- $Id: crontab.c,v 1.12 2004/01/23 18:56:42 vixie Exp $)
#50 18 * * * CMD datamove start -job_name DM_JOB_LIMIT_DETAILS -sync >> /home/out.out
#18 19 * * * sh /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/01042014_ZA/batch1.sh

#!/bin/bash
57 15 * * * /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh

Comment: Please update your question with these details. In comments it is complicated to read code.

Comment: As said, I would try with `57 15 * * * /bin/bash /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh`. Also `#!/bin/bash` in crontab is not doing anything, I would delete it.

Comment: not working with your suggestion. not even giving the error message.

Comment: Make sure the PATH is the same, i.e. `echo "$PATH"` while you're running as yourself and paste it into the crontab as `PATH='whatever output you got'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the script manually?

Did you try to add `sudo`in front of the commmand?

Do you run the crontab under root? Could be worth to try. Maybe there are problems with the rights.

Comment: 1. successfully executed manually
2. running crontab under root

Answer (score 0):

Try to add /bin/bash in front of /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh in crontab

Comment: as j0h4nn3s said, you should check the rights of the script. you could chmod 777 /home/dmuser/BAF_dev/production/test_CS/batch1.sh and try to run the script from cron again.